Мой вопрос заключается в том, как сделать так чтобы написанный на python telegram админ-чат-бот отвечал на команды только от админа | Telebot
@bot.message_handler(commands=['kick'])

def kick_user(message):

    chat_id = message.chat_id

    user_id = message.reply_to_message.from_user.id

    user_status = bot.get_chat_member(chat_id, user_id).status

    if user_status == 'administrator' or user_status == 6358407443:

        bot.reply_to(message, "ты дурак что ли?! кикнуть администратора нельзя.")

    else:

        bot.kick_chat_member(chat_id, user_id)

        bot.reply_to(message, f"Пользователь {message.reply_to_message.from_user.username} был кикнут.")


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
